# Recieved runtime permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, but still getting SecurityException

Tags: android

The flow goes like this. I get permission for Location(FINE and COARSE). OnPermissionGrantResult:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION:
             if(grantResults[0] == 0){
             (new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
                 @Override protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
                       getAndSetLocation();
                  }
              }).execute();
              }
             break;
        }
    }
}

public void getAndSetLocation(){
     startGPSService();
    //GPS Tracker is the GPS Service
    while(GPSTracker.location==null) {
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getLocation: "+e.getLocalizedMessage() );
        }
    }
    location = new Location(GPSTracker.location);
    stopGPSService();
}
```

GPSTracker service

```
  public class GPSTracker extends android.app.Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final String TAG = GPSTracker.class.getSimpleName();
    public static Location location;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
     }

     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");

         if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
              mGoogleApiClient.connect();
         return START_STICKY;
     }


     @Override
     public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
     Log.i(TAG, "onConnected" + bundle);
    Location l;
    try {
        l = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    }catch (SecurityException e){ //Error here
        l = null;
    }
    if (l != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "lat " + l.getLatitude());
        Log.i(TAG, "lng " + l.getLongitude());
        location = l;
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    startLocationUpdate();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended " + i);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i(TAG, "lat " + location.getLatitude());
    Log.i(TAG, "lng " + location.getLongitude());
    GPSTracker.location = location;
    lock.notify();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed ");

}

private void initLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

}

private void startLocationUpdate() {
    initLocationRequest();

    try {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }catch (SecurityException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "startLocationUpdate: ", e);
    }
}

private void stopLocationUpdate() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

}
```

Error is being thrown at onConnected even though, permission was received. Is it because the service is still not aware of the received permission or is it the way it is being executed? Or is the async task, the issue? It works fine from the second time on, but the first time, it always throws a security exception.

Exception Trace:

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Client must have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to request PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY locations.
```

Code which requests permission:

```
public static boolean checkForPermissions(Activity context, String[] permissions, final int requestCode) {
    if (permissions == null) return true;

    boolean resultFlag = true;
    final List<String> requiredPermissions = new ArrayList<>();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requiredPermissions.add(permission);
                resultFlag = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Request all permissions at once..
    if(requiredPermissions.size()!=0) {
        requestPermissions(context, requiredPermissions.toArray(new String[0]), requestCode);
    }

    return resultFlag;
}

checkForPermissions(mContext, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION);
```

Comment: Starts the service: context.startService(new android.content.Intent(context, GPSTracker.class));

Comment: do you have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in your manifest file

Comment: where is the code to request the permissions ?

Comment: provided in the latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION too.

[reference](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

Comment: Tried that too, sorry about that.

Comment: And to add, this is not how LOCATION permissions are requested anymore. Kindly look at runtime permissions. Ref: [Runtime-permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score 0):

last location is retrieved from location cache, now if you are starting app for first time there may not be any last location saved. in which case this line

```
l = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

returns `null`. now this only happens for first time because after that your app starts requesting updates and last location is no longer `null`.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of this, and hence, added 
     GPSTracker.location = location;
in onLocationChanged, but that doesn't answer why it should throw this exception

Comment: you forgot to connect to google api client. See the answer below

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to connect to `GoogleApiClient` in `GPSTracker`

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

This will do.

Comment: won't it be started as part of onStartCommand() of the service?

Comment: have you mentioned both the permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`??

Comment: Yes, both permissions are requested in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: `buildGoogleApiClient();` call this method in `onStartCommand` because `onCreate` is used to perform one-time setup procedures when the service is initially created

Comment: That actually helped and is working, kindly add it as answer

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately.